# arm-none-eabi-gcc undefined reference to math.h and complex.h functions

Tags: c, linker, embedded, arm-none-eabi-gcc

I'm trying to use `complex.h` and `math.h` in my embedded stm32f4 microcontroller code. Considering below sample code:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <complex.h>
#define PI 3.141593f
void sample_function(uint8_t s) {
    float t = (float)1 / s;
    float complex var1 = cexpf(2 * PI * I * t); // linker error undefined reference to cexpf
    float complex var2 = cexpf(2 * PI * I); // this works 
    // print creal and cimag parts of var1 and var2
}
```

the code compiles but I get the linker error for undefined reference to `cexpf`. But passing arguments known at compile time (such as `PI` and const numbers) to `cexpf`, gives no errors. This is the case for `sinf` and `cosf` functions also.

Linker options in `CmakeLists.txt`:

```
target_link_options(${APPLICATION} PRIVATE
    -T${APP_LINKER_SCRIPT}
    ${CPU_PARAMETERS}
    -Wl,-Map=${APPLICATION}.map
    -Wl,--start-group
    -Wl,--no-warn-rwx-segments
    -lc
    -lm
    # -lnosys
    -lstdc++
    -Wl,--end-group
    -Wl,--print-memory-usage)
```

And output of `arm-none-eabi-gcc -v` command:

```
$ arm-none-eabi-gcc -v 
Using built-in specs. 
COLLECT_GCC=arm-none-eabi-gcc 
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.2.0/lto-wrapper 
Target: arm-none-eabi 
Configured with: /build/arm-none-eabi-gcc/src/gcc-13.2.0/configure --target=arm-none-eabi --prefix=/usr --with-sysroot=/usr/arm-none-eabi --with-native-system-header-dir=/include --libexecdir=/usr/lib --enable-languages=c,c++ --enable-plugins --disable-decimal-float --disable-libffi --disable-libgomp --disable-libmudflap --disable-libquadmath --disable-libssp --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-nls --disable-shared --disable-threads --disable-tls --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --with-system-zlib --with-newlib --with-headers=/usr/arm-none-eabi/include --with-python-dir=share/gcc-arm-none-eabi --with-gmp --with-mpfr --with-mpc --with-isl --with-libelf --enable-gnu-indirect-function --with-host-libstdcxx='-static-libgcc -Wl,-Bstatic,-lstdc++,-Bdynamic -lm' --with-pkgversion='Arch Repository' --with-bugurl=https://bugs.archlinux.org/ --with-multilib-list=rmprofile 
Thread model: single 
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd 
gcc version 13.2.0 (Arch Repository)
```

Also in case of compiling and linking the code without `var1`, the result of `arm-none-eabi-readelf -a path/to/application.elf | grep "libmath"` is empty.

Does anyone know how should I resolve this?

Comment: It seems as if the library you link misses the function `cexpf()`. Did you check the library? [Edit] your question and add your findings. -- The second assignment (which is spelled wrong in your question)  triggers no linker error apparently because of constant folding. -- Your source is no [mre], please extend it to one.

Comment: You have to specify linking libraries **after** source code files or object files... so `gcc ... sample.c ... -lm ...`. No idea how `CmakeLists.txt` works though; it may do the right thing -- ignore my comment if it does.

Comment: When using constants it's the compiler itself that calculates the expression with MPFR.

Comment: @pmg Yes. I suspect that is the problem as mentioned in the comments here https://stackoverflow.com/a/34994216/9439683. But I too couldn't find how to do it in cmake.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the link command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after some searching I figured it out. The error could be resolved by adding the `-lm` flag after the object files. But as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62235728/9439683) the `target_link_options` command sets the options before everything else and I should have used `target_link_libraries` command for that purpose. So the line below adds the link to math library after all object files.

```
target_link_libraries(${APPLICATION} PRIVATE m)
```